# Why is iphone4S exposure adjustment for AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure so slow?

Tags: iphone, camera, avfoundation

The App I'm working on uses AVFoundation to start a video session and apply some image processing. For the processing to work, the lighting conditions must not be too bright (the exposure of the camera should not be too high).

So far on all iOS devices, switching from a dark scene (like my black table top) to a light scene (the computer screen, where the images to be processed are displayed) takes only up to 2-3 seconds to adjust exposure.

However on the iphone4S this takes a lot longer, 5-6 seconds, which is unacceptable for user experience. Has anyone had the same problem? I have tried to play with the 3 camera exposure settings:

AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose,

AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure,

AVCaptureExposureModeLocked

by setting it as:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [devices objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]) 
    {
        // Setup the device with the necessary settings
        if([captureDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose])
        {
             captureDevice.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose;
        }            
        [captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    else 
    {
        // handle failure
    }
```

but the problem remains. The closest I got to a solution is to use AVCaptureExposureModeLocked, but this locks the exposure setting upon camera startup to its current level. This means that if the video is started in light conditions, the image processing works brilliantly, but if the video is started in dark conditions, it is virtually impossible to process anything on a computer screen as it is too bright (and obviously the exposure won't adjust).

My question is therefore as follows: Is there anyway to set exposure settings on the back camera directly (rather than go through 'exposure modes'), and if not, does anything out there exist to speed up exposure adjustment?

I find it annoying that the official camera app on iphone4S does not have this problem at all as the exposure there changes in less than 2 seconds from very dark to very light. Thanks very much for any advice!